# How to integrate Fine Uploader with React Bootstrap modal?

Tags: reactjs, fine-uploader, react-bootstrap

FineUploader is great! But I have such a problem: I use React Bootstrap as my UI framework. I need upload button, but after user selects some image file, they need to deal with the image first in a modal dialog window of React Bootstrap, perhaps rotate it, or scale it, or crop it, etc. And when user clicks "Finish" button, then the image should be uploaded to the Node.js server, and display progress bar in the modal dialog body. After the server has received all of the file, then the modal dialog should be closed.

I read through the code of FindUploader, but can't find what I need. FineUploader do have FineUploaderBasic class, with it I can pass the upload button element. But I can't turn the FineUploaderBasic object into FineUploader object, and initialize the template when the modal dialog open. I can't just make the template invisible first, and display it when the modal open. Because React Bootstrap won't add modal into the DOM before user opens the modal.

So should I define a new method to turn a FineUploaderBasic object into a FineUploader object? Or is there any other way to make it?

Comment: _why_ do you want to transform an instance of Fine Uploader into one with the default UI and UI-related methods? Why not just choose one or the other?

Comment: Also not clear why you can't simply use CSS to hide and show the rendered template. This should be trivial to accomplish.

Comment: I mainly use Fine Uploader UI in the modal, but I also need a upload button before modal open. The point is: React Bootstrap won't add modal into the DOM before user opens the modal. So when should I call "new qq.FineUploader(...)", if I call it before modal open, then it will fail cause no DOM element with class "qq-template" at this time. But if I call it after modal open, I don't have an upload button

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying to do, what your modal looks like or why you want an "upload button" before this modal is opened. Without a better description of your problem, all I can suggest is to use two uploader instances.

Comment: [http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-custom](http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-custom) is the modal I use, renderOverlay() is only called when modal open, before that there is no modal elements in DOM

Comment: First I need a button, user selects an image file from disk, then in FineUploader's onSubmitted() method, I will call React Bootstrap modal componet's  handleToggle() method, then display the image in modal body, at this time I need FineUploader UI, I will add them in renderOverlay()'s return. So when to call new qq.FineUploader()?

Comment: Why do you need Fine Uploader UI in the modal? Why can't you just use it before the modal is loaded? Why do you ever need to use Fine Uploader basic without the default UI?

Comment: Because FineUploader UI is only needed to display in modal, the file should be uploaded only when user clicks a "finish" button on modal. And I can't set FineUploader to be invisible before modal open, cause modal's content is what return in renderOverlay() method. I use Fine Uploader basic just for the upload button

Comment: "And I can't set FineUploader to be invisible before modal open". Yes you can, via simple CSS.